# how to increase downloadable product size in magento?

Tags: product, downloadable, upload

I need to add downloadable product whose size may vary from 10-90MB
but while uploading the file for downloadable product it doesn't allow me to upload the file greater than 32MB.

Where can i change this upload size limit?

Comment: I need to contact the hosting provider for this?

Comment: lmgtfy.com/?q=magento raise uploade file size

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server and php configuration

Answer (score 1):

You file download depends on `server php configuration max_file_uploads and post_max_size`.

I guess that you `setting is 32M in Server.so it is not upload avaliable`

Comment: I need to contact hosting provider for this?

Comment: yes.. ...do this by hosting provider